# Deleting Numbers From A String -Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I am creating a program for a high school course and our teacher is very specific about what is allowed into our programs. We use python 2.x and he only allows if statements, while loops, functions, boolean values, and lists. I am working on a project that will print the reversal of a string, then print again the same reversal without the numbers in it but I cannot figure it out. Help please. What i have so far is this..

```
    def reverse_str(string):
    revstring =('')
        length=len(string)
        i = length - 1
        while i>=0:
            revstring = revstring + string[i]
            i = i - 1
        return revstring
    def strip_digits(string):
        l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        del (l)  rev_string


    string = raw_input("Enter a string->")
    new_str = rev_str(string)
    print new_str
```

I cannot figure out how to use the "del" function properly, how do i delete any of the items in the list from the reversed string..thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have two options for a task like this:

1. Iterate through the items in your list, deleting the ones that you *do not* want to keep.
2. Iterate through the items in your list, copying the ones that you *do* want to keep to a new list. Return the new list.

Now, although I would normally prefer option (2), that won't help with your specific question about `del`. To delete an item at index `x` from a list `a`, the following syntax will do it:

```
del a[x]
```

That will shift all the elements past index `x` to the left to close the gap left by deleting the element. You will have to take this shift into account if you're iterating through all the items in the list.

Comment: I want to delete the ones i dont wanna keep then later print them in a list

Comment: Being a newbie is not a problem. But even as a newbie, you should be able to determine that `del (l) rev_string` is a syntax error in Python, and to look up the correct syntax for using `del`.

Comment: what if i do something like... n = [(rev_string)] del n[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]..still syntax error right? -.-

Comment: i dont have to use del, my plan originally wasn't to use del, however, i picked up del along my path of researching and thought it would be easier, how would i do this with option 2?

Comment: The `del` statement works with just *one* element at a time, identified by its position in the list.

Comment: could i use chained if statements then?

Comment: I think you might be focusing too much on the actual code that you're going to write, rather than thinking about solving the problem. How do you want to remove the digits from the list? Option (1) or option (2)?

Comment: option 2 because i only have to print a list of the numbers that were deleted

Comment: Ok, so you could define a function `def remove_digits(s):` that iterates through each character in the list with `for c in s:`, and using an `if not c.isdigit():` statement, copy the characters that are not digits to a result like `result = result + c`. That should be enough to get you going.

Comment: You know, your question says "print again the same reversal without the numbers in it", but I just noticed you said "print a list of the numbers that were deleted" in your comment. These are obviously different things, and I'll leave you to sort out the difference. Good luck!

Comment: if i told you i was still confused would you tell me to settle for a "C"?

Comment: No. Based on the code you've already written in the question (to reverse the string), you should be able to work this out. I've outlined most of the code already.

Comment: well i meant print a list of the numbers that were removed from the string, sorry.

Comment: okay so adding the character to the list, how would i do that?    for c in s: ,then     result = result + c , i would need to define result right? define it as...? result = []? then what would i do with the    if not c.isdigit(): , like what would i write under that?

Answer (score 1):

Type `str` in python is immutable (cannot be altered in place) and does not support the `del` item deletion function.

Map the characters of the string to a list and delete the elements you want and reconstruct the string.

OR

Iterate through the string elements whilst building a new one, omitting numbers.

correct usage of `del` is:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> del a[1]
>>> a
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate back over the string copying it again but not copying the digits...  It would be interesting for you to also figure out the pythonic way to do everything your not allowed to.  Both methods are good to know.